# HTML - CSS | I want to implement 2 custom div shapes into my hero image but it's not going fluently

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my 'hero-image' with custom divs. I currently used 2 SVG's (within a div each) in HTML.

```html
<div class="overflow-hidden"> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="842" viewBox="0 0 1920 842"> 
    <path id="Path_4" data-name="Path 4" d="M1920-230V407H769.96L0,612V540Z" transform="translate(0 230)" fill="#252525" opacity="0.7"/> 
  </svg> 
</div>

<div class="overflow-hidden"> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1920" height="345" viewBox="0 0 1920 345"> 
    <defs> 
      <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.5" x2="0.5" y2="1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"> 
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#c0c0ca"/> 
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#91939a"/> 
      </linearGradient> 
    </defs> 
    <path id="Path_55" data-name="Path 55" d="M0,205,769.964,0H1920V345H0Z" opacity="0.7" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/> 
  </svg>  
</div>
```

This should basically become the head-section of my webpage:
[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIGfj.png)

And this is what I currently have: [current outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yySn1.jpg)

Does anybody have any idea how to properly make this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you can put them in a wrapper to which you set position to relative and than you position the images absolute
Here is jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L9vw0m5t/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="overflow-hidden first-img"> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="842" viewBox="0 0 1920 842"> 
    <path id="Path_4" data-name="Path 4" d="M1920-230V407H769.96L0,612V540Z" transform="translate(0 230)" fill="#252525" opacity="0.7"/> 
  </svg> 
</div>

<div class="overflow-hidden sec-img"> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1920" height="345" viewBox="0 0 1920 345"> 
    <defs> 
      <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.5" x2="0.5" y2="1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"> 
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#c0c0ca"/> 
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#91939a"/> 
      </linearGradient> 
    </defs> 
    <path id="Path_55" data-name="Path 55" d="M0,205,769.964,0H1920V345H0Z" opacity="0.7" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/> 
  </svg>  
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.first-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.sec-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 637px;
}
```